# ODP.NET version confusion

Tags: odp.net

I need to download the same ODP.NET version as the one installed on our server. I took a look at the oracle.dataaccess assembly version in c:\windows\assembly.

The version number there is 2.11.2.1.2.

But none of the offered downloads matches this version.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

So which one is the right one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess I would say version 11.2.0.1.2.

Comment: What makes you think so ? :-)

Comment: The version of the .net assembly will not match the version ODP. Without knowing which version of ODP was installed you had better just guess. That's what I just did.

Comment: Yeah, it's a messed up naming convention. The first digit in the assembly version will always be either 2 or 4, corresponding to the .net version. The rest of the assembly version matches the ODP version, except that it leaves out the .0 from the ODP version. Other than this, it is consistent ;)